# Can we draw horizontal bar char in iReport?

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasperserver

I want to draw horizontal stacked bar chart which will have two section. Is it possible to draw in iReport.

Thanks...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it is possible...
from properties of the normal graph select ORIENTATION as horizontal and thats it..
your task done..
as simple as that..
check out my images..
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hidden in a newer version. After selecting your chart component, you can find it after selecting *Chart Plot* among *Properties*' tabs (see picture).
Or you can type "Orientation" into *Search Property* field.

[image: Jaspersoft Studio screenshot]

EDIT: For some reason there's no "Search property" field in the first screenshot. It should be located here:

[image: Search property field]